# Can we use transformers for audio classification tasks?

Tags: reference-request, applications, transformer, sequence-modeling, audio-processing

Since transformers are good at processing sequential data, can we also use them for audio classification problems (same as RNNs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Transformers can be used to work with audio data, such as audio processing (audio classification, speaker identification, etc) ([Audio ALBERT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.08575.pdf)), speech-to-text ([Streaming Automatic Speech Recognition with the Transformer Model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.02674.pdf)), and text-to-speech ([Neural Speech Synthesis with Transformer Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.08895.pdf)).